# Heroku: can I recover database after removing the add-on?

Tags: database, heroku, add-on, heroku-postgres

I prematurely removed the Heroku Postgres Hobby Basic add-on from my account which housed a database I was using (I removed it via the dashboard). Is there any way to recover this database? I tried to add the add-on again but it was a fresh database.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have pg-backups added on?

Comment: I do, but the addon is deprecated https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups. It looks like it can now be access as part of the postgres database addon, which alas I can't access :/ In any event, the last time I backed up was three months ago (I know, f me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after talking with Heroku, I actually getting my database back. I had looked through the log files and found this command had been run:

```
$ Detach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR
```

Apparently the database wasn't actually removed/deleted but just disconnected from my account. They were able to locate it again and reattach it under a new name. Dudes were awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Once the database is removed -- it (and all of its data) are gone for good :(

If you had previously taken database snapshots using pgbackups you can likely still access the data (as another commenter mentioned).

Sorry for your loss :(